# Fitch notation proof help

Tags: logic

Can someone help me, i need to prove these two using fitch notation, I've been trying for 2 days I have no idea how to prove it, i tried assuming the contradiction but still couldn't solve it, please help me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first one is rather messy. Unpack the biconditionals on the left into conjunctions of material conditionals. Then assume A ↔ B, derive C and discharge to get (A ↔ B) → C. Then separately assume C, derive A ↔ B and discharge to get C → (A ↔ B). Then use biconditional introduction. It's rather longwinded because you have to cover all the cases.

The second one is simpler. A good rule of thumb when trying to prove a disjunction P ∨ Q using Fitch is to look for some expression R, such that R entails P, and ¬R entails Q. Then you can assume R, derive P, and hence P ∨ Q. Then separately assume ¬R, derive Q and hence P ∨ Q. So you have shown that each of R and ¬R entails P ∨ Q. Now you have to prove the law of excluded middle, R ∨ ¬R. Then you have the setup for disjunction elimination. In the case of your example, B itself fulfils the role of R.